# Section not expanding to 100% width

Tags: html, css, vuejs2

I am working with vue and trying to make my element responsive so starting with Mobile first approach. I am using normalize.css but i don't think it has anything to do with the issue. The div is not 100% width, it cuts half way through. I am using dev tool mobile tool to emulate the screen to view.
I have attached [image: screenshot] and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mahassan/eywraw8t/467046/) for the code.

```
  <div>
    <header class="container">
        <section>
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/100/arc" alt="logo">
        </section>
        <section>
           Logo text
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Call Us</h3>
            <div class="contact__info">
                <sub>Mon - Fri</sub>
                <a href="tel:12345" class="contact__info--number">12345</a>
            </div>
        </section>
    </header>
  </div>
```

Comment: @misorude the image shows the problem, my "Lorem Ipsum" section won't expand to full width. Which JSfiddle isn't able to replicate?

Comment: The fixed `width: 1326px;` on your header makes that element stretch wider than the viewport (if the latter is smaller than that), so it _overflows_ out of its parent, but does not stretch the parent itself. And _because_ that parent doesn’t stretch, the 100% with of the div inside it are still only 100% of the viewport width. What is a header with a fixed width of > 1300px doing in this in the first place, if you want to approach this “mobile first” …? Remove it or make it dynamic as well, otherwise this makes little sense as a test case for the rest of what you are doing to begin with.

Comment: @misorude yes that fixed the problem. I think I was making it for desktop only in first place and then realised mobile layout is different so start making changes and ending up confusing myself.  You may put it as answer and I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fixed `width: 1326px;` on your header makes that element stretch wider than the viewport (if the latter is smaller than that), so it overflows out of its parent, but does not stretch the parent itself. And because that parent doesn’t stretch, the 100% with of the div inside it are still only 100% of the viewport width.

What is a header with a fixed width of > 1300px doing in this in the first place, if you want to approach this “mobile first” …? Remove it or make it dynamic as well, otherwise this makes little sense as a test case for the rest of what you are doing to begin with.

Comment: Ah, that fixed it. The fixed header was part of desktop but it should be in media query.thanks.